# if() statement in login system doesn't work properly

Tags: php

The code works only if I try to login with a wrong password.
But when I try to login with a real password it will:

A) Not echo this 4 lines:

```php
        echo $email . "<br>";
        echo $password . "<br>";
        echo $dbemail . "<br>";
        echo $dbpassword; // This is hash, and echoed for testing purposes
```

B) Not jump to index.php with `header()`
Screenshot: Logging in with wrong password
[image: Logging in with wrong password]
Screenshot: Logging in with real password
[image: Logging in with real password]

Its 50 lines of code:

```php
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['login_button'])) {

        $email = strtolower($_POST['log_email']);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); //sanitize email
        $_SESSION['log_email'] = $email; //Store email into session variable 
        $password = $_POST['log_password'];
        $check_database_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        $login_row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_database_query);
        $dbemail = $login_row['email'];
        $dbpassword = $login_row['password'];
                //Echo $email, $password, $dbemail, $dbpassword
        echo $email . "<br>";
        echo $password . "<br>";
        echo $dbemail . "<br>";
        echo $dbpassword; // This is hash, and echoed for testing purposes
        $check_login_query = mysqli_num_rows($check_database_query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_database_query);   
            if($check_login_query == 1){
                if(password_verify($password, $dbpassword) == true) {
                        $username = $row['username'];
                        $user_closed_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND user_closed='yes'");
                                    
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($user_closed_query) == 1) {
                            $reopen_account = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET user_closed='no' WHERE email='$email'");
                        }
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                                    //Be logged in after some time
                                    if(isset($_POST['check_box'])) {
                                        setcookie('email', $email, time() + 86400, "/");
                                        setcookie('password', $password, time() + 86400, "/");
                                        }
                                        $check_login_query = "";
                // Go to index
                echo "redicerting to index...";
                header("location: index.php");
                    exit();
                }
            else {
                array_push($error_array, "<span class='error'>Email or password not working</span><br>");
            }
    }
    else{
    array_push($error_array, "<span class='error'>Email or password not working</span><br>");
    }
}else{
    echo "Login button not POSTed";
}
?>
```

//My form

```php
    <form action="register.php" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">
        <div id="login_wrapper">
        <label for="email">Your e-mail</label><br>
        <label id="error_email" style="color: red;"></label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="log_email" value="<?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['log_email'])) {
                        echo $_SESSION['log_email'];
                        }
                        ?>" required>
                                <br>
        <label for="password">Password</label><br>
                                    <input type="password" id="password" accept-charset="utf-8" name="log_password" required>
                                <br>
                            <?php if(in_array("<span class='error'>Email or password not working</span><br>", $error_array)) echo  "<span class='error'>Email or password not working</span><br>"; ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check_box">Remember me<br>
                    <br>
                <a href="#" id="signup" class="signup">Dont have an accout? Sign Up!</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Log from `error.log`:

```
[Mon Jan 21 15:22:44.064393 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 11540:tid 1960] [client ::1:61860] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: userLoggedIn in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\drope\\index.php on line 70
[Mon Jan 21 15:43:43.163934 2019] [php7:crit] [pid 11540:tid 1960] [client ::1:63802] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\drope\\includes\\form_handlers\\login_handler.php on line 4
```

Maybe i've written bad `if()` or i have bugs in code, but i didnt see any errors..
Also is this secure? Or how can i improve security? Maybe not store hash in cookies, but how can i keep user logged in after clearing `$_SESSION`s?
//Notice: Problem isn't in session_start, i have started session already.

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You didn't declare `session_start()`

Comment: `$_POST['login_button']` isn't set if you're getting that `Login button not POSTed` message.

Comment: I have tarted session before, in different file

Comment: But i clicked button..

Comment: I only see error if i use bad password

Comment: Please add your form

Comment: You have to have `session_start();` at the top of all pages using sessions.

Comment: I have added form, and @JayBlanchard i tried, but not working, problem is its not redicerting to index

Comment: Guys, problem isnt in session_start, ```Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started```

Comment: Can you show the console log of data you're sending ?

Comment: Guess: the login is working just fine, but it's redirecting to this page again using a GET request, so `$_POST['login_button']` is no longer set…

Comment: i can, but problem is in back end, once it works , once not :/

Comment: Can you try removing the redirect to try ? For console log go into your browser using `F12` and in networks tab and go into your file and check the data

Comment: @deceze how can i fix it?

Comment: Don't have a pointless `else{ echo "Login button not POSTed"; }`…?! ‍♂️

Comment: When i remove redicert i will see white page with:

Comment: ```emrici@izotopy.sk
ahojahoj
Emrici@izotopy.sk
$argon2i$v=19$m=1024,t=2,p=2$WjhtR2Z3Z2Y3Smtsd0sycA$Gtn9Pg/6ob97Fdb4cOJKKx9E6jSW9IAOxy/In4XuXv```

Comment: Update: If i use working password it will add 4 echos on top of page, and if i use real password it will show white page with 4 echos

Comment: This else isn't pointless, it signalizes ```if(isset($_POST[''login_button]))``` returns false, but idk why

Comment: So any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in `index.php` file. It seems to redirect you back to `register.php`